# React-Native Google Maps search result

Tags: ios, google-maps, react-native, geolocation, maps

I want to show a search query results map in react-native,
for example:

https://www.google.it/maps/search/hotels+in+New+York,+Stati+Uniti/@40.7522488,-74.0240238,13z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=it

I have checked at several components:
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps
https://github.com/tolu360/react-native-google-places
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/installation.md

I successfully installed cocoa dependencies and set up the Google APIs.

What i am looking for is an Around Me feature with Google Maps results

Comment: If you can get the query results including location data, then i think u can use Markers to map them using react-native-maps package, is this what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution, for me was to use the AirBandB React Native Maps component. It provides every feature you need to work with google maps (and not only google maps).

This is a beautiful Video Tutorial serie about it, it's really clear and work great.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT8SssHz0nY